# Javascript Map function chaining

Tags: javascript

I just came across one thing and I cannot find an answer why is this happening so maybe someone can help.

This is the piece of code

```
function titleCase(str) {
  let arr = str.split(" ")
    .map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
    console.log('arr1', arr)

let arr2 = str.split(" ")

  arr2.map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
  console.log('arr2', arr2)
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

I am interested in why arr1 (when map is chained immediately after split is working as expected. It returns `["I'm", "A", "Little", "Tea", "Pot"]`, but arr2 is returning `["I'm", "a", "little", "tea", "pot"]`

Should this type of writing (whether it is chained or not) return the same key? What am I missing?

Comment: `.map` returns a new array, it doesn't mutate the original. So `arr2.map()` just does something and throws away the result.

Comment: @VLAZ but arr 1 also returns a new array since it's using map.

Comment: It does return it and you retain that as `arr`. In the second case you don't retain the result of the `.map`.

Comment: @VLAZ ok I made a small demo and yes, works like you said. But can you tell me why is that happening? Shouldn't that be the same thing?

Comment: Again, `.map` returns a *new array*. If you don't save it, then you will not have it. It's similar as having `str2 = "hello" + "world"` and just `"hello" + "world"` by itself. A new string will be constructed but never saved. Same with `.map` - a new array is created and never saved.

Comment: @VLAZ aaah. Makes sense. Now I get it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the former, your variable is being assigning the result of operations `split` followed by `map` on your array. In the latter, your variable is being assigned only the result of `split`.

So, this:

```
let arr = str.split(" ")
   .map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
```

is equivalent to:

```
let arr2 = str.split(" ")
arr2 = arr2.map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
```

i.e. you forgot to do the assignment `arr2 =` in case of `map`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for map:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results

That means it doesn't change the original array, but gives you a new one. So when you do

```
arr2.map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
console.log('arr2', arr2)
```

Map is returning a new array, but you have no variable to store the new array that .map creates. So

```
const result = arr2.map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
console.log('result', result)
```

Will work.

In contrast if we check out the documentation for sort:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place

So it is changing the same array and not giving you new one.

Answer (score 0):

it is because in this line

```
let arr2 = str.split(" ")<----- this is what you get from console.log()

    arr2.map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
  console.log('arr2', arr2)
}
```

you are using `console.log(arr2)` which is assinged to be equal to  `str.split(" ")`

for you second line to work you have to assign arr2.map a variable and then you will be able to print it in the console like this

```
const arr2=arr2.map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
      console.log('arr2', arr2)
    }
```